# SaaS model with database per user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant, saas

I want to create SaaS web-application using Spring and Hibernate. 
I suppose that we will get many customers(companies) and each company has her own database. All companies have db with same schema. Also we have one administrative db which stores special info, like users, passwords, logins etc. 
  I think that for realization this project i should use hibernate multi-tenancy. But I can't find appropriate examples for my task.
 This the list of things i want to understand:

1. Where we can store connections properties(url, port, db name, db user, db password). Should it be property file or administrative db?
2. I suppose that we can create all beans(dataSource, etc.) for db connection runtime after company's account creation or before first user of company will sign in. Where we can store all created datasources? How we can check if datasource already exist?

Comment: `Where we can store connections properties(url, port, db name, db user, db password)` consider security. Create a user with the minimum permissions/access sufficient.

Comment: I am not a Java developer, however, the tenants properties should reside within the administrative database. I would also like to suggest that you explore on single sign on instead of handling the user password in the administrative database. HTH